# How to trigger a recyclerview scroll listener when it is inside a scroll view?

Tags: android

How to trigger a recyclerview scroll listener when it is inside a scroll view?

Here the scroll view listener is alone triggering

Comment: post some code plz

Answer (score 2):

**1. Set nested scrolling enabled false of recycler view.**

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

**2. Add scroll listner to nested scrollview.**

```
 mScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new 
ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
           @Override
           public void onScrollChanged()
           {
                    View view = (View)mScrollView.getChildAt(mScrollView.getChildCount() - 1);

                    int diff = (view.getBottom() - (mScrollView.getHeight() + mScrollView
                                    .getScrollY()));

                    if (diff == 0) {
                       // your pagination code
                    }
           }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`.

> NestedScrollView is just like ScrollView, but it supports acting as both a nested scrolling parent and child on both new and old versions of Android. Nested scrolling is enabled by default.

**Note:** You have to set `setNestedScrollingEnable(false)` to your `recylerview`.

- in `xml` add `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` in `recyclerview`

**`OR`**

- programmatically `yourRecylerview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`

See [this article](https://android.jlelse.eu/recyclerview-within-nestedscrollview-scrolling-issue-3180b5ad2542).

Answer (score 0):

*You can try this one, but still I assuming you may have the same code like mine as you didnot post your needed code into your question.*

**Try this:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="never">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
     </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Use `NestedScrollView` with `<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`  as I have mention above.

Answer (score 0):

Its ScrollListener will not work as all the rows gets layed when recyclerview is inside scrollview whole purpose of recyclerview gets destroyed when you put it inside scroll view.

For Example as the recyclerview will stretch to full fill its parent ,when you will put it inside scroll view , in case of scroll view it will stretch to its fullest. if there are 1000 items in recyclerview all it will draw 1000 different rows which is also a performance issue.

You should remove it from a scroll view to make its scroll listener working